# Nested JSON with aspjson

Tags: json, asp-classic

I want to generate some JSON in an ASP AJAX response in the form

```
{
  "Result":"OK",
  "Records":[
    {"Id":1,"Name":"Ben"},
    {"Id":2,"Name":"Doug"},
    {"Id":3,"Name":"Isaac"}
  ]
}
```

I'm using [aspjson](https://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) and have got the "Records" from my database using

```
<%@Language="VBScript" %>
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/Includes/db_connection_inc.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/jquery/JSON.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/jquery/JSON_util.asp" -->
<%
    Dim cnn, crs, oRSeof
    tablename = "[myDB].[dbo].[Driver]"
    Set cnn = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open DB_CONNECTION
    Set crs=CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    sqlQuery = "SELECT drvID, DriverName FROM Driver"
    rsJSON = CStr(QueryToJSON(cnn, sqlQuery).Flush)
    Response.Write rsJSON

    Set crs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
%>
```

What is the correct way to embed that result into the outer object as the Records set / structure?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution from tugrulto's comment on https://code.google.com/p/aspjson/wiki/SQLtoJSON.

```
<%@Language="VBScript" %>
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/Includes/db_connection_inc.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/jquery/JSON.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE virtual="/jquery/JSON_util.asp" -->
<%
    '{
    ' "Result":"OK",
    ' "Records":[
    '  {"drvID":1,"Driver":"Ben"},
    '  {"drvID":2,"Driver":"Isaac"}
    ' ]
    '}

    tablename = "[readymix].[dbo].[Driver]"
    Set cnn = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open DB_CONNECTION
    Set crs=CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    sqlQuery = "SELECT drvID, Driver FROM " & tablename

    set jsout = jsObject()
    jsout("Result") = "OK"
    Set jsout("Records") = QueryToJSON(cnn, sqlQuery)   '<-- The important bit.
    jsout.Flush

    Set crs = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
%>
```